# EditText Service Class

Tags: android

How come EditTexts does not bring up the keyboard by default in a Service class? I have tried so many different methods and not a single one works. No crashes either. I am so confused on why it is so hard to do so. It shows when it is focused on it, but nothing comes from it. Can someone please help me. If you would like more code, please don't hesitate to ask. Here is a code snippet:

```
        final EditText opHexEdit = new EditText(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opHexEditParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opHexEdit.setLayoutParams(opHexEditParam);
        opHexEdit.setHint("Ex: 01 00 A0 E3 1E FF 2F E1");
        LL3.addView(opHexEdit);
```

Here is an image of the output:
[image]

More code. This is all I will showcase due to how hungry android leechers are:

```
final RelativeLayout collapsedView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams collapsedViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        collapsedView.setLayoutParams(collapsedViewParam);
        collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menuHolder.addView(collapsedView);

        final RelativeLayout expandedView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams expandedViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        expandedView.setLayoutParams(expandedViewParam);
        expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        expandedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        menuHolder.addView(expandedView);

        final ImageView pmtIcon = new ImageView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pmtIconParam = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(175, 175);
        pmtIcon.setLayoutParams(pmtIconParam);
        collapsedView.addView(pmtIcon);
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/pmt/images/pmt_icon_round.png");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
        pmtIcon.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        final LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL.setLayoutParams(LLP);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        expandedView.addView(LL);

        final LinearLayout LL1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL1P = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL1.setLayoutParams(LL1P);
        LL1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.addView(LL1);

        final TextView opBlankSpaces = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpacesParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpaces.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpacesParam);
        opBlankSpaces.setText("    ");
        opBlankSpaces.setTextSize(26);
        LL1.addView(opBlankSpaces);

        final TextView opTitle = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opTitleParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opTitle.setLayoutParams(opTitleParam);
        opTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opTitle.setTextSize(38);
        SpannableString underline = new SpannableString(" Live Offset Patcher ");
        underline.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, underline.length(), 0);
        opTitle.setText(underline);
        LL1.addView(opTitle);

        final TextView opBlankSpaces1 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpaces1Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpaces1.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpaces1Param);
        opBlankSpaces1.setText("    ");
        opBlankSpaces1.setTextSize(26);
        LL1.addView(opBlankSpaces1);

        final TextView opBlankSpace = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpaceParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpace.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpaceParam);
        opBlankSpace.setText(" ");
        opBlankSpace.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opBlankSpace.setTextSize(12);
        LL.addView(opBlankSpace);

        final LinearLayout LL2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL2P = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL2.setLayoutParams(LL2P);
        LL2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.addView(LL2);

        final TextView opOffsetText = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opOffsetTextParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opOffsetText.setLayoutParams(opOffsetTextParam);
        opOffsetText.setText(" Offset: ");
        opOffsetText.setTextSize(17);
        opOffsetText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        LL2.addView(opOffsetText);

        final EditText opOffsetEdit = new EditText(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opOffsetEditParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opOffsetEdit.setLayoutParams(opOffsetEditParam);
        opOffsetEdit.setHint("Ex: 0x002864AC");
        LL2.addView(opOffsetEdit);

        final LinearLayout LL3 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL3P = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL3.setLayoutParams(LL3P);
        LL3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.addView(LL3);

        final TextView opHexText = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opHexTextParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opHexText.setLayoutParams(opHexTextParam);
        opHexText.setText(" Hex: ");
        opHexText.setTextSize(17);
        opHexText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        LL3.addView(opHexText);

        final EditText opHexEdit = new EditText(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opHexEditParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opHexEdit.setLayoutParams(opHexEditParam);
        opHexEdit.setHint("Ex: 01 00 A0 E3 1E FF 2F E1");
        LL3.addView(opHexEdit);
        opHexEdit.requestFocus();

        final LinearLayout LL5 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL5P = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL5.setLayoutParams(LL5P);
        LL5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.addView(LL5);

        final TextView opLibText = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opLibTextParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opLibText.setLayoutParams(opLibTextParam);
        opLibText.setText(" Lib: ");
        opLibText.setTextSize(17);
        opLibText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        LL5.addView(opLibText);

        final EditText opLibEdit = new EditText(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opLibEditParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opLibEdit.setLayoutParams(opLibEditParam);
        opLibEdit.setHint("Ex: libil2cpp");
        LL5.addView(opLibEdit);

        final TextView opBlankSpace1 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpace1Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpace1.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpace1Param);
        opBlankSpace1.setText(" ");
        opBlankSpace1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opBlankSpace1.setTextSize(13);
        LL.addView(opBlankSpace1);

        final LinearLayout LL4 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams LL4P = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LL4.setLayoutParams(LL4P);
        LL4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.addView(LL4);

        final TextView opBlankSpaces2 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpaces2Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpaces2.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpaces2Param);
        opBlankSpaces2.setText("  ");
        opBlankSpaces2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        LL4.addView(opBlankSpaces2);

        final Button sendItButton = new Button(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sendItButtonParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        sendItButton.setLayoutParams(sendItButtonParam);
        sendItButton.setText("   Modify   ");
        sendItButton.setTextSize(17);
        sendItButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        sendItButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));
        LL4.addView(sendItButton);
        sendItButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                offset = opOffsetEdit.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Offset Patched: " + offset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final TextView opBlankSpaces3 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpaces3Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpaces3.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpaces3Param);
        opBlankSpaces3.setText("  ");
        opBlankSpaces3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        LL4.addView(opBlankSpaces3);

        final Button closeButton = new Button(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams closeButtonParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        closeButton.setLayoutParams(closeButtonParam);
        closeButton.setText("   Close   ");
        closeButton.setTextSize(17);
        closeButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        closeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));
        LL4.addView(closeButton);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Offset Patcher Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final TextView opBlankSpace2 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpace2Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpace2.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpace2Param);
        opBlankSpace2.setText(" ");
        opBlankSpace2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opBlankSpace2.setTextSize(18);
        LL.addView(opBlankSpace2);

        final TextView opCredits = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opCreditsParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opCredits.setLayoutParams(opCreditsParam);
        opCredits.setText(" ~ Liquified @Platinmods.com");
        opCredits.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opCredits.setTextSize(18);
        LL.addView(opCredits);

        final TextView opBlankSpace3 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams opBlankSpace3Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        opBlankSpace3.setLayoutParams(opBlankSpace3Param);
        opBlankSpace3.setText(" ");
        opBlankSpace3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        opBlankSpace3.setTextSize(18);
        LL.addView(opBlankSpace3);

        expandedViewF = expandedView;
        collapsedViewF = collapsedView;
```

Comment: what is LL3 view?

Comment: can you show us the output view?

Comment: LL3 is my LinearLayout

Comment: Can you show your XML ?

Comment: I do not have an xml. Xml files are way too easily editable.

Comment: There is no dialogue. This is a RelativeLayout view I created. This is a floating overlay.

Comment: I mean layout of your Activity or the layout that is include the edittext ?

Comment: I do not have a layout file. This is all done in my service java class.

Comment: try `opHexEdit.requestFocus()` after `final EditText opHexEdit = new EditText(this);`

Comment: @samirk433 no result

Comment: can you try it after adding to layout, i.e. `LL3.addView(opHexEdit);` If it doesn't work you should post the whole layout coding

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it did not work. I am going to grab my pizza real quick , and I will be back.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);   
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Try This.

Answer (score 0):

The forth parameter for overlayParam was originally set to FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE. Changing it to FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL fixes the problem but causes another problem. Apps just simply do not work, but at least this first problem, the question, has been answered.

```
        int overlay;
        final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            overlay = 2038;
        }
        else {
            overlay = 2002;
        }
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams overlayParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                overlay,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        overlayParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        overlayParam.x = 0;
        overlayParam.y = 0;
```